# Parse Signup Problems

Tags: swift, parse-platform

So, I wanted to create a new social media app using Swift and Parse. When I go to the Parse site, and click on dashboard, it gives me a login screen. I don't have an account, so I click on the "I don't have a parse account" button. When I click on that, it just takes me back to the home page. I did manage to get the code and frameworks and stuff that I needed from the docs, but that didn't quite work. It gave me this for the initialize code:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "YOUR_APP_ID"
    $0.server = "http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse"
}
```

In the tutorial I'm watching, rather than "YOUR_APP_ID" and "http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse" it just had a bunch of letters and numbers, which I would assume are the app ID and Parse server. My guess is, that I need an account to get those. Would that be correct? And, does anyone know why I can't seem to get an account? Thanks.

Comment: `I don't have an account` Parse.com is shutting down - they don't accept creating new accounts anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com is shutting down, so that's why you are not allowed to create new accounts on the service. Check [the blog post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-parse-server-and-the-database-migration-tool/).

They open sourced a nodeJS implementation, which you should definitely check out at [link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server), and here is an [example](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) to get you started. You can easily use the deploy buttons to host the server on services like Heroku, AWS, Azure, etc. You can also deploy a server locally, for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's true that Parse is discontinuing early next year, you can still setup a new app if you want to use the service for a shorter term project. Replace your code with the following.

```
   Parse.setApplicationId("YOUR-APP-ID", clientKey: "YOUR-CLIENT-ID")
```

You can find your App ID and Client ID in your app's settings > security & keys.

EDIT: You definitely need an account for this to work.